# Integration of barcode scanner ZXing in Android Error

Tags: android, zxing, classnotfoundexception

I've learned from this website :
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

I've got two little problems with integration of Zxing :

1. My application's name is now "Barcode scanner"
2. I've got this error when I want to use the integrated barcode scanner : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : android.preference.set`

But,
when I choose to use the barcode scanner (previously installed on my smartphone), there are no errors !
Have you got any idea ?

My code is :

Manifest :

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Activity :

```
    /* -- LISTENER CLICK SCAN PRODUCT -- */
View.OnClickListener bScanProduct = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.w("SuggestionActivity", "Scan receved : "+contents+" format : "+format);
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.w("SuggestionActivity", "Cancel scan");
        }
    }
}

/*----------------------------------*/
```

The project "CaptureActivity" is set as library, and include in my project.
And the core.jar is also include as an "External JAR".

Comment: show your code of how you "use integraded barcoded scanner". show your **excact** stacktrace of ClassNotFoundException. Perhaps show your manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't follow this blog post. It is showing you how to copy and paste our app, which is strongly discouraged, for a reason you are highlighting right here. Intentionally or not, people create clone apps that use the same icon, *name*, and Manifest settings, which interfere with apps integrating with the real Barcode Scanner by Intent.

Reusing parts of the code in *your own app* is OK, if you know what you are doing, but if you are surprised by the name thing, I doubt this is the case.

In fact, in your edit, you show you are trying to integrate by `Intent`. This is far easier and requires none of the `core/` or `android/` code.

Correct integration instructions are found in the project itself: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Please integrate this way if you are not sure enough about how this works to responsibly reuse the source code of Barcode Scanner.

Comment: With that code, when I try the code, Eclipse can't import the IntentIntegrator... Code : IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();

Comment: (You need to add the classes in `android-integration`. There are just two, so if it's easier, just copy the source.)